# Environment - Assigning attributes in override_attributes using references to other attributes

Tags: chef-infra

My understanding of chef roles is that in roles everything is static because the role content is loaded and parsed as json. Not substitution will take place etc.
But what about the content of the environment which can be either a json or rb file?

Reason for asking is because I want to be able to reuse values in the environment file specified in one recipe by referencing them in a second recipe.

To better explain my problem, imagine in the code below that the two first recipes http_service and mysql_service "own" their values name, ip and port.
In the monitor recipe it is possible to declare multiple monitor endpoints. But the recipe does not know of the actual recipes  - http_service and mysql_service here - it only needs the name, ip and port. 
This is way I would like to avoid duplication of the ip when assigning the values in the monitor and also not have the monitor recipe know about the other recipes - it needs to remain generic in this case. 
I known the syntax used is wrong but I hope it communicates the intention.
Can this be done somehow?
I prefer the "declare once and reference elsewhere" idea. :)

```
"override_attributes": {

"http_service":{
      "name": "Service_1",
      "ip": "10.10.10.1",
      "port": "8080"

  },
  "mysql_service":{
      "name": "Service_2",
      "ip": "10.10.10.2",
      "port": "3306"
  },
   "monitor":{
        "monitor_endpoints":
            [
                        {
                        "servicename": node[:http_service][:name],
                        "ip": node[:http_service][:ip],
                        "port": node[:http_service][:port]
                        },
                        {
                        "servicename": node[:mysql_service][:name],
                        "ip": node[:mysql_service][:ip],
                        "port": node[:mysql_service][:port]
                        }
                ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `node[:xenserver][:ip]` in your recipe, if you can easily use `node[:infrastructure][:network][:gateway]` without introducing any new attributes/variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in a JSON environment. You can do this in a recipe:

```
node.override['xenserver']['ip'] = node['infrastructure']['network']['gateway']
```

But remember, if it feels wrong, it probably is wrong.

Comment: Even though I have updated the example I am guessing your answer will be the same: not possible in JSON. But what if it was done in Ruby? Is that environment file parsed in the same manner no matter if it is json or ruby?

Comment: It won't work properly if the environment is in Ruby. And your environments should just be data, so JSON is better than Ruby, imo

Comment: Ok. thanks for the answer. I guess duplication is the way to go then. It is just really a shame since I find the ability to reference in the env file very powerful.